# Узнать максимум и минимум по центру массива

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть массив, размер которого вводится пользователем. Необходимо посчитать максимум и минимум по центру массива.
 Просьба помочь в этом, самому разобраться не выходит. 
 Или хоть идею, как это сделать.

п.с. Сам пробовал всякие махинации с n (размер массива), например, n/4+n/4, 3*n/4 и т.п.

Comment: Что, извините, посчитать? О.о

Comment: >максимум и минимум по центру массива

Что это?

Comment: что-то я не пойму как вычисляются пределы центра массива.

Comment: Я так понимаю, если решать в лоб, то тупо массив сортируем, потом берем первый, последний и центральный элементы.

Comment: Извиняюсь,если не правильно выразился.  Для пояснения задачи: Массив в этом случае,можно представить как отрезок,в котором нужно найти значения находящиеся по центру (т.е. допустим отрезок делится на 3 части,нужно найти самое большое и самое маленькое число в средней части,не затрагивая числа из других частей)

Comment: Ну так и в чем проблема? Пишем функцию, просматривающую последовательно все элементы массива от, положим, n1 до n2, которые передаем как параметры, и находящую максимум и минимум, и вызываем ее с соответствующими аргументами. Или код никак не получается написать?

Comment: Если честно,как написать подобную функцию слабо представляю,пытался через цикл сделать. Если можешь напиши,как сделать функцию просматривающую элементы массива,дальше уже сам смогу :)

Comment: Если n длина массива a[], то печать середины что-то такое (l и r начало и конец середины (одной трети массива))

    for (l = n/3, r = n-l; l < r; l++)
        printf ("%d ",a[l]); // l пробегает по всем элементам середины

По желанию можно скорректировать на +/-1 l и r (подумайте, как лучше).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Как я понял задачу, то сделать это можно так:**

1. Определить четность массива(пл количеству элементов в нем)
2. Если четный, то берем два элемента, которые стоят посередине. 
      Затем сравниваем их, находим наибольший и наименьший(из двух!)
3. Если массив нечетный, то делаем все то же самое, но только с тремя элементами,
      находящимися в середине(первый элемент - середина(допустим, b), 
      а следующие два - это b+1 и b-1).

Иначе, если не так, то суть задачи - простое нахождение наибольшего и наименьшего 
элементов массива, потому что серединой массива можно назвать и пространство **от единицы** до **длины массива-1**.

Answer (score 2):

Функция для обнаружения  значения минимального и максимального элементов в массиве `arr` длиной `n`

```
void minmax (int arr[], size_t n, int& min, int& max) {
    max = min = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i]; 
    }
}
```

Можно в виде шаблона:

```
template <class T> void minmax (T arr[], size_t n, T& min, T& max) {
    max = min = arr[0];
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max) max = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] < min) min = arr[i]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Не забываем ставить плюсики